# In R, How to apply if statement in matrix

Tags: r

recently I am trying to mimic a game.
I am going to throw 2 dice at the same time. If the sum of 2 dice is greater than or equals to 10, I win 1 point.
If it is lower than 10, I lose 1 point. I will do this for 1000 times.

At the very beginning, I draw 2000 random samples with set.seed (1234)

```
set.seed(1234)
d = sample(c(1:6), size = 2000, replace = T)
d
```

And then, I turn it into a matrix, and sum each row

```
a = matrix(d, nrow=1000, ncol=2, byrow=T)
t = rowSums(a)
t
```

Now, I have 1000 elements (sum of two dice each time). I would like to create a vector X to calculate the point that I can get.
However, how can I apply if statement to create vector X in this time?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
X <- ifelse(t>=10,1,-1)
```

or

```
X <- 2*(t>=10)-1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
case_when(t >= 10 ~ 1, TRUE ~ -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a temporary variable and assign points by comparing the values.

```
tmp <- t
t[tmp >= 10] <- 1
t[tmp < 10] <- -1
```

Or without a temporary variable.

```
t1 <- c(-1, 1)[(t >= 10) + 1]
```